# Unable to debug - symbols missing

Tags: debugging, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, debug-symbols, iis-10

I am unable to debug an api developed in ASP.NET core.
API is hosted in IIS and if I execute the request through fiddler,
I do get the response back. However, if I wish to debug the api for some reason, it's not working because symbols have not been loaded.

I tried following options.

1) Running VS in ADMIN mode.

2) verified this setting @
 Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)

3) Added IIS_USERS and IUSER @ IIS Virtual directory security section and granted full rights.

4) Project is built in debug mode.

5 ) debugging information is set to Portable (Project properties->Build->Advanced)

6) Ran Regiis utility..

Following modules did not get loaded when verified the modules and not sure if this is causing any issue?

aspnetcore.dll, rewrite.dll, iisres.dll

NOTE: If I create a normal application i.e. any windows app and attach a debugger. all modules get loaded and I am able to debug.

Please advise.

Comment: Could you load the symbols now?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT - No, still no luck, tried all options but it still says unable to load the symbol. I am using community edition, could that be an issue that community edition might not have all required files ?   I tried creating webapi in ASP.NET Webapplication with VS 2017 community edition and able to debug... this issue is only with ASP.NET Core WebAPI.

Comment: I got the same issue using the Web API project, it seems that some symbols were not uploaded to the servers, other members also reported this issue before:https://github.com/dotnet/home/issues/69

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to:

- Clean your solution on VS
- Close VS
- Delete /bin e /obj folders.
- Open VS
- Rebuild solution.
- Try to debug

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In VS in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General there is an option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode", please uncheck this option.

[image]